# Need help resolving error message

Tags: grails

Just tried to deploy a .war file and received this error message. This came quite the surprise to me because I just deployed a .war file the day before and worked fine with minimal changes between the two (changed a value of a variable that tracks days until a cron job executes). I do leave out the auto generated .iml files that IntelliJ creates, could that do it?

```
'2014-01-24 08:47:45,480 [Thread-10] WARN  config.ConfigurationFactory  - No configuration found. Configuring ehcac                                              he from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/var/opt/tomcat/webapps/PerformanceEvaluations-moved                                              /WEB-INF/lib/ehcache-core-2.4.6.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
''2014-01-24 08:47:46,117 [Thread-10] WARN  hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - Couldn't find a specific ehca                                              che configuration for cache named [edu.wisc.radiology.performanceevaluations.Role]; using defaults.
'    ==> PerformanceEvaluations_main.log <== '2014-01-24 08:47:45,480 [Thread-10] WARN  config.ConfigurationFactory  - No configuration found. Configuring ehcac                                              he from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/var/opt/tomcat/webapps/PerformanceEvaluations-moved                                              /WEB-INF/lib/ehcache-core-2.4.6.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
''2014-01-24 08:47:46,117 [Thread-10] WARN  hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - Couldn't find a specific ehca                                              che configuration for cache named [edu.wisc.radiology.performanceevaluations.Role]; using defaults.
'    ==> catalina.out <==
'2014-01-24 08:47:49,046 [Thread-10] WARN  servlet.DefaultGrailsApplicationAttributes  - ApplicationContext not fou                                              nd in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.APPLICATION_CONTEXT attribute of servlet context.
' ==> PerformanceEvaluations_main.log <==
'2014-01-24 08:47:49,046 [Thread-10] WARN  servlet.DefaultGrailsApplicationAttributes  - ApplicationContext not fou                                              nd in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.APPLICATION_CONTEXT attribute of servlet context.
' ==> catalina.out <==
'2014-01-24 08:47:50,112 [Thread-10] WARN  module.ModuleDeclarationsFactory  - 'grails.resources.modules' in config                                               does not define any modules
'==> PerformanceEvaluations_main.log <==
'2014-01-24 08:47:50,112 [Thread-10] WARN  module.ModuleDeclarationsFactory  - 'grails.resources.modules' in config                                               does not define any modules
' ==> catalina.out <==
Parsing DB Changelog
```

Comment: found this post 
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Unsolvable-warnings-due-to-db-reverse-engineer-plugin-td4427619.html

Comment: this seems to have a similar issue, the problem being the error logging is turned up too high

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any error messages, only warnings. And all are harmless. For example the one about Ehcache is standard. If you don't provide a custom ehcache.xml, it defaults to one in the jar file and prints some messages to that effect. You can create your own - typically a modified version of the default file - and put it in the root of the classpath (non-Groovy files in grails-app/conf and src/java get copied to the classpath, so it's a good location) and it will be used instead. This is a good idea to do early on, even if you just keep the default values in your file, to make it easier to configure later. And the defaults are rather conservative, e.g. the TTL defaults to only 2 minutes.